# Natural Composite Key vs Single Surrogate Key in sql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

```sql
create table Section
(
    section_surr_id serial not null,
    curr_id int,
    section_id int not null,
    foreign key (curr_id) references Curriculum(curr_id)
);

create table Lesson
(
    lesson_surr_id serial not null,
    curr_id int,
    section_id int, 
    lesson_id int not null,
    uri varchar not null,
    title varchar not null,
    description varchar,
    foreign key (curr_id) references Curriculum(curr_id),
    foreign key (section_id) references Section(section)
);
```

Here's the broad overview of what the I want to do: Curriculum HAS MANY sections; each section HAS MANY lessons

In the `Lesson` table I want to include `section_id` because each lesson belongs to a particular section; but I have created a surrogate key for section that uniquely identifies each section.

The reason for that was each curriculum has a number of sections so if I had made `section_id` the primary key, then it could have been repeated, like section 1 of Curriculum 1 and section 1 of curriculum 2; therefore I had two options:

- create a composite natural key composed of `curr_id` and `section_id`
- or create a surrogate single column primary key

Now what key do I reference in lesson; if I reference the surrogate key, then that wouldn't be natural because I would have to look for the surrogate key of the section I want to refer like 1,2, 3 etc of the desired curriculum.

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one "right" answer, so this borders on an opinion-based question, which Stack Overflow discourages.

I would create a compound primary key.

```
create table Section
(
    curr_id int not null,
    section_id int not null,
    primary key (curr_id, section_id),
    foreign key (curr_id) references Curriculum(curr_id)
);
```

Then reference it with a compound foreign key. The opinionated part is that one may keep the serial key in the `Lesson` table, or not. Either of the following are correct:

```
create table Lesson
(
    lesson_surr_id serial not null,
    curr_id int not null,
    section_id int not null, 
    lesson_id int not null,
    uri varchar not null,
    title varchar not null,
    description varchar,
    foreign key (curr_id, section_id) references Section(curr_id, section_id)
);

create table Lesson
(
    curr_id int not null,
    section_id int not null, 
    lesson_id serial not null,
    uri varchar not null,
    title varchar not null,
    description varchar,
    primary key (curr_id, section_id, lesson_id),
    foreign key (curr_id, section_id) references Section(curr_id, section_id)
);
```

It comes down to personal preference.